# Why can I overload istream's operator>> for strings?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, iostream

Suppose I wanted `operator>>` to extract entire lines from an `istream` instead of whitespace-separated words. I was surprised to see that this, although horrible, actually worked:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

namespace std {
  istream &operator>>(istream &is, string &str) {
    getline(is, str);
  }
}

int main() {
  std::string line;
  std::cin >> line;
  std::cout << "Read: '" << line << "'\n";
}
```

If I type multiple words into stdin, it actually does call my operator and read an entire line.

I would expect this definition of `operator>>` to conflict with the [official one](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/operator%3E%3E/), producing a link error. Why doesn't it?

---

Edit: I thought maybe the real `operator>>` was a template, and non-template functions take precedence, but this still works just as well:

```
namespace std {
  template<typename charT>
  basic_istream<charT> &operator>>(basic_istream<charT> &is, basic_string<charT> &s) {
    getline(is, s);
  }
}
```

Comment: [The signatures don't look quite the same](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_ltltgtgt). P.S: [Don't use cplusplus.com](http://kera.name/articles/2013/02/cplusplus-com-is-bad-and-you-should-feel-bad/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It *happens* to work because the official template [is less specific](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_ltltgtgt) (there are additional template arguments).

However it is [Undefined Behaviour™](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?UndefinedBehavior). You are only permitted to provide overloads of standard library symbols for your own types. If you come across another standard library that will define extra overloads (it may), it will stop working and you won't know why.